# Unable to open Xamarin Studio on Windows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

After upgrading to version 6.x of Xamarin Studio, I am now unable to launch Xamarin Studio on Windows.

I did receive an error about missing Microsoft Build Tools, however I am not sure if that is a requirement, as I did not have issues with the previous version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a requirement in Xamarin Studio to include Microsoft Build Tools, both 2013 and 2015. In order to launch Xamarin Studio on Windows, Microsoft Build Tools 2013 and 2015 must both be installed manually from the following links:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Thanks!